# Approximating a Riemann integrable function using a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f$ be Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$. Show that for every $ε > 0$, there is a continuous function $g$ on $[a,b]$ such that 
$$\int_a^b |f(x)−g(x)|\mathrm dx < ε. $$

Comment: OK. Have you thought about Darboux sums with regard to Riemann integrability?

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the following theorem:

> If $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, then $f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$ and for each $\epsilon>0$ there exists a partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ such that 
>   $$U(P,f)-L(P,f)<\epsilon$$
>   where $U,L$ denote Darboux upper sum and Darboux lower sum, respectively.

Given any $\epsilon>0$, there corresponds a partition $P:=\{x_0,x_1,\cdots,x_n\}$ (of course $x_0=a,x_n=b$) such that 
$$U(P,f)-L(P,f)<\frac{\epsilon}{b-a}$$
Let
$$u(x)=\begin{cases}\sup\{f(t)\mid\ t\in[x_k,x_{k+1}]\},\quad & x\in[x_k,x_{k+1}),\, k=0,1\cdots,n-1 \\f(b),&x=b\end{cases}$$
and 
$$l(x)=\begin{cases}\inf\{f(t)\mid\ t\in[x_k,x_{k+1}]\},\quad & x\in[x_k,x_{k+1}),\, k=0,1\cdots,n-1 \\f(b),&x=b\end{cases}$$
You should be aware that (why?)
$$\int_a^b u(x)\mathrm dx=U(P,f),\quad\text{and}\quad\int_a^b l(x)\mathrm dx=L(P,f)$$
Now, consider $g(x)$ defined as follows
$$g(x)=\begin{cases}\displaystyle{f(x_k)+\frac{f(x_{k+1})-f(x_k)}{x_{k+1}-x_k}(x-x_k)},\quad &x\in[x_k,x_{k+1}),\,k=0,1,\cdots,n-1\\ f(b), &x=b\end{cases}$$
show that $g(x)$ is fulfilling by noting that 
$$l(x)\le f(x),g(x)\le u(x)$$
and hence that 
$$\int_a^b|f(x)-g(x)|\mathrm dx\le \int_a^b|u(x)-l(x)|\mathrm dx<\epsilon$$